# On average what number of questions would you get right on a 60 question paper with each question having 4 choices?

Tags: probability, statistics

Of course we are assuming you don't know an asnswer to a single question and use only luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Binomial Law $ B(n,p), $ in our case $ n=60 ,p=\frac{1}{4}$ . $ E= n*p= 60*\frac{1}{4}=15$

Answer (score 0):

On average you would get 1 out of 4 right so 60/4 = 15.

Answer (score 0):

you have a 25% chance for to get the right answer so you we get approximately $\frac{60}{4}=15$

Answer (score 0):

OK... the mean is clearly $15$.  But the *variance* is $60 \cdot (1 - 1/4) \cdot 1/4 = 45/4$.